# Using "modern" batteries with old devices

Tags: batteries, computers

I have a Sony Vaio p-series laptop which is a tiny computer build in 2009. It is a wonderful device but the battery is only 2500 mah and lasts about 1.5 hours.

My phone battery on the other hand is a quarter of the size, 4500 mah, and lasts almost a day and a half with heavy use. My question is, what would it take to make an upgraded battery for the little laptop? Assuming I had access to some big cell phone batteries, let's say. Can I just wire it in somehow? I assume the new battery would have to match some kinds of numbers so that it inputs and outputs energy at the same rate... Or something like that... I am pretty well-versed in how operating systems work but have no experience with actually building anything. Is this idea totally infeasible or do I just need to learn how to do it and obtain the right parts?

Comment: What is the voltage on the battery in that laptop? It should be on a label somewhere. Cellphone "batteries" are really single cells, and the batteries in these notebook class machines are usually two or three cells in series to form a battery.

Comment: It says "7.4V(cc7,4V)"

Comment: If it's 7.4V it's probably a Lithium Polymer battery.  You may be able to get 50% more usage with modern cells the same size, but whether you can find anything that fits, and whether having higher-capacity cells will confuse the Vaio's charge-management hardware is a tossup.  I'd start by doing a web search to see if I can find someone with replacement batteries, or a how-to on changing out the cells for new ones.

Comment: Your phone, BTW, has about 10 years of progress at making electronics less power-hungry.

Comment: Hm. It seems like an external powerbank is probably the most viable solution. When you say 10 years of progress you are referring to hardware right? Or is it some kind of firmware? The "charge management" isn't some kind of program?

Comment: lower power CMOS...

Comment: Charge management for laptops is either done in the laptop itself with dumb batteries, or it is done in smart batteries that will communicate with the laptop.  An example of a smart battery is the one used in Dell laptops.  They use a custom chip combo from TI to control charging.  The only role the laptop plays is verifying the power supply is usable(Dell power supplies are intelltigent) via a 1wire serial protocol.

Comment: Your phone lasts all day because it goes into low power modes the second you put it in your pocket... That lap top battery I would guess has the same WHr rating as your phone or close. Amps is only half the equation.

Comment: @MadHatter  We were told the size of both batteries.  2500 mAh. for the laptop and the phone battery is 1/4 the size and is 4500 mAh.  I think it's due to a couple of reasons, 10 years of tech advancement, phones are normally VERY aggressive in using low power modes,  laptops follow OS recendations, very very different hardware(regular hard drive vs SD card, full size hardware(CPU and MEM) vs SOC, possible optical drive, much much larger screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current (Amps) is not the total power storage of a battery. Cell phone batteries are all 3.7V so they are often compared by the mAh rating of the battery. In reality to calculate run time you need to use Watt Hour (Wh) which is the total amount of energy stored. 

To find total Energy storage of a battery (assuming battery capacity given in amp hours):
\$E[WattHours] = P[watts]*time[hours] => V*I*1hr \$.

Old Battery: 7.4v x 2500mAh = 18.5 Wh

Cell Phone: 3.7v x 4500mAh = 16.7 Wh

So your modern cell phone battery actually still holds less power then your "old" Lithium Ion battery in the laptop. While battery technology is always getting better, it is not moving as fast as you may think.

Per my comment, laptops are very power hungry compared to a phone that spends 90% of its time sleeping in your pocket. Also modern electronics constantly require less power to run, thus resulting in a longer run time for a given battery size.

**Update About Size:**

I missed the 1/4 the size in the question originally. Given that info, It would seem that a modern battery would have a higher power density and thus provide a longer run time. The hardest part would be getting cells that match the batteries form factor, since most laptop batteries are made to fit the form of the unit. If the battery could be created out of typical 3.7V cells that are available on various online marketplaces, then there is a chance you could do something. Although you would still need to ensure the battery has a similar interface for charging and add some sort of a battery protection circuit that basically all multi cell packs have.

Comment: Power = Watts W. Stored energy = Watt-hours Wh

Comment: @tomnexus For comparison it does not matter since everything is normalized to an hour. mAh vs mA is the same thing for comparison here. I was trying to keep it simple for OP, I'll make it correct per physics since people seem to be upset by the simplification.